# How can I use a gitlab deploy token from ansible?

Tags: git, ansible, gitlab

My company has a self-hosted GitLab server.
I'm writing an Ansible playbook that configures a server by using several projects from our GitLab server.

In order to have the target server clone the projects automatically (non-interactively), I'm using deploy tokens.

First, on our GitLab server's web interface, I went to my first project and generated a deploy key for it. I can configure the target server to use the deploy key using ansible with something like this:

```
- name: Have git store credentials on disk
  community.general.git_config:
    name: credential.helper
    scope: global
    value: store

- name: Add credentials for project A
  copy:
      dest: /root/.git-credentials
      content: "https://{{ gitlab_project_A_deploy_username }}:{{ gitlab_project_A_deploy_password }}@company_gitlab_server.com"

- name: Clone Project A git repo
  git:
    repo: 'https://company_gitlab_server.com/USER/Project_A.git'
    dest: /some/dir/
```

I set `gitlab_project_A_deploy_username` and `gitlab_project_A_deploy_password` in the ansible vault. This works great, except that in `/root/.git-credentials`, the credentials are not git-repo specific - they are server specific.

When I get a deploy key for Project B, it has a completely different username and password, but the server is the same. Even if I add both sets of credentials to `/root/.git-credentials`, the `git` ansible module, or even just the regular `git` binary would have no idea which credentials to use when cloning a project.

Is there a way to somehow specify one deploy key for one project, and a different deploy key for a different project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just set the credentials directly into the repo path?

```yaml
- name: Clone Project A git repo
  git:
    repo: 'https://{{ gitlab_project_A_deploy_username }}:{{ gitlab_project_A_deploy_password }}@company_gitlab_server.com/USER/Project_A.git'
    dest: /some/dir/
```

Comment: What if i want to use the token?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a helper for the credentials (whether `store` or `cache`) you can use the [`credential.useHttpPath`](https://manpages.debian.org/gitcredentials#CONFIGURATION_OPTIONS) option to make it match on the path too.

Then, for the store helper, save

```
https://{{ gitlab_project_A_deploy_username }}:{{ gitlab_project_A_deploy_password }}@company_gitlab_server.com/USER/Project_A.git
https://{{ gitlab_project_B_deploy_username }}:{{ gitlab_project_B_deploy_password }}@company_gitlab_server.com/USER/Project_B.git
```

in the credentials store.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work this way, using `https://{{ gitlab_user }}:{{ gitlab_token }}@gitlab.com/<project-url>.git`

```py
- name: Git clone repo to '{{ ansible_user }}'
  vars:
    # project token name is used for "user"
    gitlab_user: '<your-proect-token-name>'
    # setup this token at gitlab, for project token
    # testd with devloper read api, read repo, read
    #   registry, Role developer
    gitlab_token: '<your-project-token>'
    #install to this users dir/permission
    ansible_become_user: '{{ ansible_user }}'
  # become ansible user so we can use its ssh key
  #need root access
  become: yes
  ansible.builtin.git:
    repo: 'https://{{ gitlab_user }}:{{ gitlab_token }}@gitlab.com/<project-url>.git'
    dest: ~ansible/
    #single_branch: yes
    version: master
```